# 2 Custom Post Types In 1 Archive Page?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-post-type-archives

I have 2 custom post types (announcements and news) and I want to have their own archive pages (which I have, and they're working) and an archive page that shows both posts types ordered by date.

How can I tell wordpress to give me all the posts of 2 custom post types?

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php get_template_part('template-parts/archive-announcement-content', get_post_type()); ?>
<?php else: ?>
<p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to go. The 'traditional' way I think would be to create a "[Page Template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/)", and on that template use a custom query ([WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/)) to display the posts from the two post types ordered by date. You'd then add a WordPress "Page" in the control panel and choose your new template from the Attributes panel at the left.

This is a sample of how that page template might look:

```
<?php
/**
* Template Name: News & Announcements Archive
*/

$args = array(
    'post_type' => array( 'announcement', 'news' )
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : 
    // Start the Loop 
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
        get_template_part('template-parts/archive-announcement-content', get_post_type());
    // End the Loop 
    endwhile; 
else: 
// If no posts match this query, output this text. 
    _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.', 'textdomain' ); 
endif; 
 
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

In newer versions of WordPress, though, you could skip that step and use a Block to display all the posts from those two post types. In future versions of WordPress I think this will be possible via core Blocks, but right now (WP 5.8.2) you'll have to either build the Block yourself or use a plugin that provides such a block.